# Division by using 2 cut variables

Tags: bash, division, cut

I have the following code :

```
#!/bin/bash
pontos=$(cat condutores.txt | cut -d ":" -f 10)
nviagens=$(cat condutores.txt | cut -d ":" -f 9)
divisao=$((pontos / nviagens))
echo $divisao
```

I want to divide the 10th column of each line  with 9th column of `condutores.txt`. Save it in a variable and check if the number is less than 5 . However the division does not work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this in one line using awk! Suppose I have sample data (which I am using to mimic yours):

```
1       15      18
2       17      6
3       14      98
4       17      25
5       9       3
```

This is how you divide column 3 by column 2 using awk:

```
awk '{print $3/$2}' example_file.txt
```

prints to standard output:

```
1.2
0.352941
7
1.47059
0.333333
```

Now say from this I wanted only those values which were less than 1:

```
awk '{if ($3/$2 < 1) print $0}' awk_tester.txt
```

returns the full rows:

```
2       17      6
5       9       3
```

now if we want the actual value:

```
awk '{if ($3/$2 < 1) print $3/$2}' awk_tester.txt
```

returns:

```
0.352941
0.333333
```

If your field separator is ':' just add this to the beginning of each awk command:

```
-F ':'
```

like so:

```
awk -F ':' '{if ($3/$2 < 1) print $3/$2}' awk_tester.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your division does not work out, is that `cut` gives you the full column. So if `condutores.txt` has many lines you will get many values there all separated with `\n`. This is not really a number to divide.

You might try something else ...

```
awk '{print $9/$10}' FS=":" condutores.txt
```